# Update UI from another thread

Tags: android

I know that update UI from another thread is forbidden, so I tried that to see what result I will get from the application. Yes, the app will crash when updating the UI component, but there is one case I don't understand, the app run fine.

**1)**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        new Thread(){ //1                       
            public void run() {                             
                tv.setText("changed");                      
        }}.start(); //1  }  
    }
```

**2)**

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        bt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                 new Thread(){ //1                       
                        public void run() {                             
                            tv.setText("changed");                      
                    }}.start(); //1  }  
            }

        });


    }
```

Sorry for my previous description of my problem, I think most people misunderstand it, so I rephrase the question. There are 2 scenario above, they are supposed to give me crashing error because both create new thread and update the UI component, but in fact, only the second scenario crash but fisrt scenario  does not crash. Anyone know the reason?

Comment: runOnUiThread or create handler in UI thread (for example make it in a class as a field or final Handler as local variable) and then use handler.post. Runnable will be the argument of these function and code inside is to what you want to do in UI thread

Comment: Hi thank your reply. I am still not very clear what do you mean. Is this feature exist in adroid or it exist in J2SE as well? Usually I was able to create new thread by using this way in J2SE, am I right?

Comment: I have rephrash the question, could be easier to be understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this exception

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-19449
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4357)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChild(ViewRootImpl.java:802)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:851)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652):    at android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4312)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8603)
E/AndroidRuntime( 7652):    at android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:8554)
```

UI thread checking only be checked in invalidate(rendering) time. 
So in create time(onCreate),  there is no problem.

You can add Thread.sleep(5000) before setText and the above exception will happen.

Comment: oh man, you rock! I think you found the reason. Your answer make the most sense. Thanks.

Comment: oh man I do not have enough reputation to vote up. You deserved a thumb up.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
private void startthread() {
anihandler = new Handler() {

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
    super.handleMessage(msg);

     tv.setText("changed");
}

};

aniThread = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
 sleep(1000);
                 anihandler.sendMessage(anihandler
                        .obtainMessage());


}
};

aniThread.start();
}
```

Comment: I have rephrash the question, could be easier to be understood.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Threading, use asynctask for this kind of operation. It's all described [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) and very easy to use.

Comment: I have rephrash the question, could be easier to be understood.